# create Dense layers in a loop

Tags: keras

I need to create multiple dense layers by for loop, the number of iteration depends on the number of labels. I want to create one dense layer for each label. Each label has a different set of features, so I want to predict each label separately with corresponding feature set in each dense layer. Is that possible? The following code is my attempt.

```
layers = []
for i in range(num_labels):
    h1 = Dense(num_genes_per+10, kernel_initializer='normal', input_dim = num_genes_per, activation='relu')(inputs)
    h2 = Dense(int(num_genes_per/2), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(h1) 
    output= Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(h2)
    layers.append(output)

merged_output = concatenate(layers, axis=1)
model = Model(inputs, merged_output)
```

The output of each h2 will have shape [batch, 1], and the merged_output will have shape [batch, num_labels]. Is there any error in the above code?

I know it is not efficient, but if I concatenate the different set of features into one input tensor, and use only one dense layer to predict all labels at same time, would it harms the prediction accuracy?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. You are creating parallel dense layers each of which supposed to predict one label. It's like have n networks to predict n labels and far from efficient. If you stack those layers the network capacity to learn will increase.

Comment: @Mehraban But each label has a different set of features, so I want to predict each label separately with corresponding feature set in each dense layer. I know it is not efficient, but if I concatenate the different set of features into one input tensor, and use only one dense layer to predict all labels at same time, would it harms the prediction accuracy?

Comment: You mean the input to each of these `h1` layers are different?

Comment: Sounds like masking might help you. If the feature isn't there, input a zero in it's place and mask all zeros.

Comment: @Mehraban Yes, like (feature1, feature2, feature3) for h1, (feature4, feature5, feature6) for h2, (feature7, feature8, feature9) for h3.etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you defined features and labels. If features 1, 2 and 3 are used to predict label 1 and they have no relation to label 2, It does not make sense to include it in label 3 inference.

Comment: It's not absolutely has no relation, just some case that features 1 2 3 has high correlations with label1 but low correlations with label2, so I want to predict each label only with the features that has high correlations with them

Comment: @HenryBai So I'll recommend you to include all the features in training samples of all classes and let the network figure it out how to weight these features in prediction.